# not receive any verification code when google calender api calls

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I am trying to implement google calendar API.

I am following every step of [Google Document quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php) .

also, follow cmd instructions like first `composer require google/apiclient:^2.0` then `php quickstart.php` it gives me the link to open in the browser.

I have open that link in the browser but it shows me to enter verification code but I haven't received any verification code.

and also it redirects on quickstart.php only and not redirect on page which I enter in redirct_uri in the google console.

can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extend the original question concerning "enter verification code":  I don't see this screen. I get the regular "choose your account", then "are you sure you want to give this site permission", then it redirects back to Quickstart php with the same link and "enter verification code" ..I showed to a developer, he was baffled. What would cause it to skip the screen mentioned above?
I am using the Google API quickstart for php code example with no modifications

Answer (score 0):

When you open the link you will see a screen, asking you to sign in with the account you're using with your project.

[image]

Then, it will ask you to allow the scope access, you will only need to accept them.

[image]

And then you will get the code that you will need to paste in your CLI.